# value being changed to random number on function call?

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Shapes.h"

int main()
{
    //variables
    int height = 0;
    int width = 0;

    Rectangle rect = Rectangle();
    Triangle tran = Triangle();
    Square sqar = Square();

    std::cout << "What is the width of the shape? ";
    std::cin >> width;
    std::cout << "What is the height of the shape?";
    std::cin >> height;
    rect.set_lengths(width, height);
    std::cout << "If the shape is a triangle, the area is " << tran.area() << "." << std::endl;
    std::cout << "If the shape is a rectangle, the area is " << rect.area() << "." << std::endl;
    std::cout << "If the shape is a square, the area is " << sqar.areaByWidth() << " by the width value," << std::endl;
    std::cout << "and " << sqar.areaByHeight() << " by the height value." << std::endl;
    system("pause");
}
```

Header file:

```
//Our base class
class Shape 
{
protected:
    int width, height, shapes = 0;
public:
    void set_lengths(int width, int height)
    {
        width = width; height = height;
    }
};

//Rectangle is a shape
class Rectangle : public Shape 
{
public:
    Rectangle()
    {
        std::cout << "Created a rectangle!\n";
        shapes = shapes + 1;
    }
    ~Rectangle()
    {
        shapes = shapes - 1;
    }

    int area()
    {
        return width * height;
    }
};

//Triangle is a shape
class Triangle : public Shape 
{
public:
    Triangle()
    {
        shapes = shapes + 1;
        std::cout << "Created a triangle!\n";
    }
    ~Triangle()
    {
        shapes = shapes - 1;
    }
    int area()
    {
        return width * height / 2;
    }
};

//Square is a shape
class Square : public Shape 
{
public:
    Square()
    {
        shapes = shapes + 1;
        std::cout << "Created a square!";
    }
    ~Square()
    {
        shapes = shapes - 1;
    }
    int areaByWidth()
    {
        return width * width;
    }
    int areaByHeight()
    {
        return height * height;
    }
};
```

When I set the values, it works fine (shows the correct value in visual studio debugger), but when I call area() it brings back -846388729 or something similiar?  Why is the value being reset?  I have been banging my head against a wall for hours on this.  Seems like a common problem to noobies like myself but I'm not understanding the other solutions on here :(

Comment: You only called `set_lengths()` on `rect`, but not on `tran` nor `sqar`.

Comment: @defube, [Nothing wrong with it.](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8a0f9df93485be73)

Comment: @defube hmmm...  Haven't even looked at that yet, I'll check whats going on there.

Comment: Your base class is missing a virtual destructor and your shapes counting is broken.

Comment: @timrau it doesn't work for any of them, including rect

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function `set_lengths` did not set the member variable correctly, just set the value back to the function arguments.

change

```
void set_lengths(int width, int height)
{
    width = width; height = height;
}
```

to

```
void set_lengths(int width, int height)
{
    this->width = width; this->height = height;
}
```

Or change the name of the member variables for a good habit:

```
int width_, height_, shapes_;
void set_lengths(int width, int height)
{
    width_ = width; 
    height_ = height;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Becuase `width` and `height` are not initilized.

[image]

Change the line to:

```
int i = 0, j = 0, k = 0;
```

Also, you're only setting the dimension of the `rect` object, not the triangle or the square.